# Tomcat can't set 'source' property set in Host Context server.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, netbeans

We have a web application running under Tomcat from Netbeans, I'm attempting to get it running under Tomcat from eclipse.

I created a server in eclipse, specifying the same tomcat 7 installation on my machine that is used to run from Netbeans. I understand that, when one does this, eclipse copies the catalina.base server files over to its own temp directory to keep them separate.

It also evidently makes some changes to the server.xml that it uses. In server.xml in the tomcat directory, the Host tag is this:

```
  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
```

But in the eclipse environment, it's

```
  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn"/>
    <Context docBase="myApp-war" path="/myApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myApp-war"/>
   </Host>
```

after eliminating whitespace and comments.

Our problem is (evidently) that the runtime doesn't have a `source` property to which to assign the value in the `Context` tag. We found no `source` documented in the Tomcat 7.0 documentation for 'Host / Context', and at runtime we have the following in the Console:

```
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:salespoint-war' did not find a matching property.
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\local;c:\devTools\apache-maven\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;c:\Program Files\Apache\apache-cxf-3.1.6\bin;C:\Windows\system32;;.
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
```

We figure it cannot handle SSL connections because it is unable to initialize the connector. We also don't know why it wouldn't be able to find the APR library, since this is the same installation of Tomcat used by Netbeans, and it gives no such error message then.

Can anyone help us understand what's going wrong here? We figure there's some kind of configuration thing we've missed.

*IN CASE IT'S RELEVANT* - There used to be similar SetPropertyRule warnings about several other APR-specific properties found in our connector configuration. We added `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"` to the Connector to make the APR protocol explicit, evidently Netbeans infers it or takes it as default or something. That eliminated the APR-property-specific warnings, but left us with this one.

=== EDIT

Here are the two connectors we have in server.xml:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>

<!-- SSL Connector Configuration-->
<Connector 
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.base}\conf\ssl_crt\mycert\server.crt" 
SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.base}\conf\ssl_crt\mycert\server.key" 
SSLCipherSuite="RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH:!SSLv2:@STRENGTH" 
SSLEnabled="true" 
SSLPassword="webapps.accesspointinc.com" 
SSLProtocol="all" 
acceptCount="100" 
compression="on" 
compressionMinSize="2048" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
enableLookups="false" 
executor="tomcatThreadPool" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
maxThreads="200" 
port="8443" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true"/>
```

And the entire log file, including the error messages:

```
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:salespoint-war' did not find a matching property.
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;c:\local;c:\devTools\apache-maven\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin;C:\Perl64\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;c:\Program Files\Apache\apache-cxf-3.1.6\bin;C:\Windows\system32;;.
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:821)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: The configured protocol [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] requires the APR/native library which is not available
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:972)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more

Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 789 ms
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.63
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "/salespoint" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1302)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.setWebAppRootSystemProperty(WebUtils.java:146)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:269)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5017)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5531)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "c:\Program Files\apache\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\logs\applications\salespoint.log" "write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkWrite(SecurityManager.java:979)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:203)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:136)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    ... 17 more

Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/salespoint] startup failed due to previous errors
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.<clinit>(ContextCleanupListener.java:43)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5726)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "*" "read,write")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:366)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:555)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(SecurityManager.java:1269)
    at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.removeWebAppRootSystemProperty(WebUtils.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.shutdownLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextDestroyed(Log4jConfigListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5064)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5726)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 12, 2017 1:23:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 6175 ms
```

Comment: The complaint about the non-existent `source` attribute is not causing your TLS problems. Eclipse puts that attribute into your configuration and Tomcat doesn't know what to do with it. In order to debug your TLS problem, you need to post your `<Connector>` configuration as well as the complete error message you get about the failed connector-initialization.

Comment: Added as edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling Tomcat to use the APR connector, and the APR library cannot be located. Your `java.library.path` system property has a very large number of paths in it:

- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin`
- `C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin`
- `C:\Windows\system32`
- `C:\Windows`
- `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\bin`
- `C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/server`
- `C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/bin`
- `C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91/lib/amd64`
- `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
- `c:\local`
- `c:\devTools\apache-maven\bin`
- `C:\Perl64\site\bin`
- `C:\Perl64\bin`
- `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin`
- `C:\Windows\system32`
- `C:\Windows`
- `C:\Windows\System32\Wbem`
- `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\`
- `C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\`
- `c:\Program Files\Apache\apache-cxf-3.1.6\bin`
- `C:\Windows\system32`
- `.` (the current working directory of the process)

If this works "in Netbeans", then I suspect that one of the following are the problem:

1. NetBeans is specifying a different `java.library.path` system property when launching Tomcat
2. NetBeans is using a different current-working-directory when launching Tomcat

In either case, the `tcnative` library must be in a place that Tomcat can find it. You need to put the `tcnative`, `apr`, and `openssl` libraries all in a location that is present in the `java.library.path` system property.

I would recommend putting them in a predictable directory (like `%CATALINA_HOME%/bin`) and then explicitly-setting `java.library.path` to `%CATALINA_HOME%/bin` when launching Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for a complete and thoughtful answer. I searched for "tcnative" and found "tcnative-1.dll" in %CATALINA_HOME%\bin, so it's already there. A "%C_H%\\webapps\docs\Apr.html" page says Apache Portable Runtime (APR) requires the APR library, JNI wrappers (libtcnative), and OpenSSL libraries. It also says tcnative-1 is a statically compiled .dll including OpenSSL and APR. So the APR and OpenSSL are there, I'm not sure about the wrappers. I'll try it.

Comment: I put -Djava.library.path=c:\blah\blah into the command line parameters for the JDK under Window / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs / Edit, and that seems to have worked; I'm no longer getting the Connector error. I'm now getting a permission error concerning the logger, which I'll work on Monday; it's too late in the week and the day to start on that now.

Comment: If you get `tcnative.dll` directly from Apache then it is usually statically-linked, and you do not need a separate `apr.dll` and `openssl.dll`. It's a good idea to have `openssl.exe` around, though.

Comment: About the system property; you probably want to set that system property in the Tomcat service itself, and not in the general Java system properties. That library path is only valid for running Tomcat, and maybe only a specific Tomcat (if you for example have multiple Tomcat-based services running).

Comment: Again, thank you. Eclipse has a setting for the running of java via eclipse; I can set it there, since this is my development machine and this is all it used for. I suppose I should think about the case when we do development on something else within eclipse, however. I'll keep it in mind. Just have to figure out where in the startup of things I can set that. Is there a preferred place?

Comment: It's all about your deployment environment. If you are using Windows Services then there's only one place that setting can appear: in the service definition itself. If you are using scripts to launch Tomcat (like `catalina.bat`), then `bin/startup.bat` was designed for just such a purpose.